# Download, Extract and Import images from Zip to Angular 4 Application

Tags: angular, http, zip

I have a following problem. The API that I have to consume is returning me a ZIP file. Within this zip there are some images that I need to load and display in my component's HTML. I am running Angular 4 application, I got stuck on a first step as my promise is returning HTML parse error. I presume it is necessary to set somewhere the expected return type.

Any help is welcome, but a guideline how to perform all three operations of downloading, extracting and again importing files would be most helpful.

```
public getStudyMediaFiles(studyId: number){
  let url = environment.endpoint + `getImgs/${studyId}`;
  return this.http.get(url).toPromise().then(response => {
      let res: any= response;

      console.log(res);

      if(res.code == 0){
          return res ;
      }else {
          this.globalService.showNotification('top','center', res.message, 'danger');
      }

  }).catch(this.handleError);}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you intend to do with these files later. Should they be saved permanently? This likely should be performed on server side, thus this question isn't specific to Angular.

Comment: sorry for not making it clear @estus, my intention is only to load them in the client application, for like a gallery preview. Images are already saved on the server, I simply want to request zip, extract it and display on the client. No server tampering is allowed

Comment: All all three operations are separate operations that should be addressed separately. You can unzip files with some third-party lib like https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js . If you're unsure how extracted image string should be bound in view, that's a different question, and I'm sure it has been already answered on SO.The question isn't specific enough and currently falls into 'write the code for me' category. It will have better chances to be answered once it will address specific problems you've encountered during implementation.